# How to extract A2 from GCSO*A2*001*202 using regex

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I am trying to extract second element after * on " GCSO*A2*001*202" using regex. Any Idea?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.  Also, regex might not be the way to go if you can `split` on the asterisks.

Comment: Yes,  the idea is to use `explode`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other commenters that splitting on * would be a better approach, but if you're set on using regex then:

```
\*(.*?)\*
```

Will cause the first capture group, `$1` to contain `"A2"`